# Retrofit 2.0 Cant convert Request Body to JSON

Tags: post, request, gson, retrofit

I hope someone can help me.

I try to send a POST Request with a JSON Body using Retrofit 2.0.

Interface:

```
public interface Interface {
  @POST(/*path*/)
  Call<MyResponseObject> sendInt(@Body MyInteger myInt);
}
```

MyInteger class:

```
public class MyInteger {
    int id;

    public MyInteger(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Part of MainActivity:

```
private Retrofit mRetrofit = null;
private final Interface mService;
...
...
mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(/*URL*/)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
mService = mRetrofit.create(Interface.class);
```

The call:

```
MyInteger id = new MyInteger(0);
mService.sendInt(id).enqueue(new Callback<MyResponseObject>() {
  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<MyResponseObject> call, Response<MyResponseObject> response) {/*Log something*/}

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<MyResponseObject> call, Throwable t) {}
});
```

In my Opinion it's like this example:
https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body

But the GsonConverter cant convert MyInteger to JSON..
Here is the Log:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create @Body converter for class com.??.MyInteger (parameter #1)
                                                                                                   for method Interface.sendInt
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate RequestBody converter for class com.??.MyInteger.
                                                                                             Tried:
                                                                                              * retrofit2.BuiltInConverters
                                                                                              * retrofit2.GsonConverterFactory
                                                                                               at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextRequestBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:288)
                                                                                               at retrofit2.Retrofit.requestBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:248)
                                                                                               at retrofit2.RequestFactoryParser.parseParameters(RequestFactoryParser.java:491)
```

Comment: My workaround is now to send a RequestBody Object of retrofit instead of my own myInteger Object.
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myIntegerObject);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), josn);

Comment: You need to generate getter and setter for MyInteger class or make int id public.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The root cause was that I was using incompatible libraries.

This combination works for me:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: i'm using the same dependencies with gradle:
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'

Comment: What I would have done next is to step trough the process in the debugger and try to understand why it fails. You could also try in a different environment, for example with a newer Java version. I can't see anything wrong with your code. (However, I'm new to Retrofit and I'm using it synchronously for now, so don't take that as a thorough code review).

Comment: You saved my day!!